# I want to query EDNS with Bind, what's edns-disabled?

Tags: dns, bind

I start Bind in 9.11.2. I want to query some site with EDNS, but I got this problem. How should i do?

```
13-Nov-2017 08:05:34.970 dnssec: debug 4: validator @0x7f44897f0f20: dns_validator_destroy
13-Nov-2017 08:05:34.970 edns-disabled: info: success resolving 'www.gds.alibaba.com/A' (in 'gds.alibaba.com'?) after disabling EDNS
13-Nov-2017 08:05:34.970 database: debug 5: dns_adb_destroyfind on find 0x7f4484bd9e20
13-Nov-2017 08:05:34.970 database: debug 5: dns_adb_destroyfind on find 0x7f4484bcae20
13-Nov-2017 08:05:34.970 client: debug 3: client @0x7f44897c7480
```

I turn on the log at level 5(`rndc trace 5`). I'm confused, how?

```
13-Nov-2017 08:05:34.970 edns-disabled: info: success resolving 'www.gds.alibaba.com/A' (in 'gds.alibaba.com'?) after disabling EDNS
```

What's edns-disabled？

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the remote name server that your BIND server tried to talk do doesn't correctly support EDNS ([RFC 6891](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6891)), so BIND failed-over to "plain" DNS instead.

In this particular case, the server is dropping queries that contain the new EDNS Cookie option ([RFC 7873](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7873)) which are sent by default in BIND 9.11.  Dropping the packets in this way is contrary to the EDNS specification.

It is possible to disable sending the EDNS Cookie option by creating a `server { }` directive in your `named.conf` file with `send-cookie no;`

See also https://ednscomp.isc.org/ where there's more information about EDNS (non-)compliance and a compliance testing tool.

The results for `gds.alibaba.com` are at https://ednscomp.isc.org/ednscomp/004c393a64